# helm understanding alerts on grafana promoteus stack alert

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager

can someone help me understand the ‘interval: 5m’, ‘relativeTimeRange’ , ‘intervalMs’ and ‘maxDataPoints’ ?

I am using this yaml:

```
      groups:
      - orgId: 1
        name: statefulset status
        folder: derms
        interval: 5m
        rules:
          - uid: f37b5c90-7485-4adf-b056-d216df1d1d0c
            title: statefulset
            condition: C
            data:
              - refId: A
                relativeTimeRange:
                  from: 600
                  to: 0
                datasourceUid: prometheus
                model:
                  editorMode: code
                  expr: sum(kube_statefulset_replicas) by (namespace, statefulset) - sum(kube_statefulset_status_replicas_ready) by (namespace, statefulset)
                  hide: false
                  instant: false
                  intervalMs: 1000
                  maxDataPoints: 43200
                  range: true
                  refId: A
              - refId: B
                relativeTimeRange:
                  from: 600
                  to: 0
                datasourceUid: __expr__
                model:
                  conditions:
                      - evaluator:
                          params: []
                          type: gt
                        operator:
                          type: and
                        query:
                          params:
                              - B
                        reducer:
                          params: []
                          type: last
                        type: query
                  datasource:
                      type: __expr__
                      uid: __expr__
                  expression: A
                  hide: false
                  intervalMs: 1000
                  maxDataPoints: 43200
                  reducer: last
                  refId: B
                  type: reduce
              - refId: C
                relativeTimeRange:
                  from: 600
                  to: 0
                datasourceUid: __expr__
                model:
                  conditions:
                      - evaluator:
                          params:
                              - 0
                          type: gt
                        operator:
                          type: and
                        query:
                          params:
                              - C
                        reducer:
                          params: []
                          type: last
                        type: query
                  datasource:
                      type: __expr__
                      uid: __expr__
                  expression: B
                  hide: false
                  intervalMs: 1000
                  maxDataPoints: 43200
                  refId: C
                  type: threshold
            noDataState: NoData
            execErrState: Error
            for: 10m
            annotations:
              summary: |
                {{` {{ $values.B }} {{ $labels.statefulset }} pod(S) in namespace {{ $labels.namespace }} are not running. `}}
            labels:
              SendTo: slack
              Severity: critical
            isPaused: false
```

I understand that it evaluate the rule every 5 minute, but will send alert only if the alert happen for 10 min?

if in between the pod statefulset was running, will it not alert?

Is this a good example of using the grafana alert?

at first I thought to make it check every 30 min, and give the pod another 5 min to come back, but I understand this is not how it is working… (?)